# Is "enjoy having" the right phrase here?

Tags: phrase-requests, phrase-usage

> Being a newcomer, she still didn't **enjoy having** her co-workers' help. Not
>   even their attention.

If not, what's a better option?

(The meaning is: her co-workers didn't help her because she was new in the company and they didn't know her well.)

Comment: I think you need to specify in your question exactly what you're going for. "Enjoy having" is used colloquially in a sarcastic way, so I don't know if it really makes sense in narration.

Comment: The meaning of the sentence you ask about means that her co-workers ***did*** help her but she didn’t like it when they did. She didn’t even like just their attention.

Comment: Genuinely ambiguous.

Comment: Consider using the simpler "she didn't *get* her co-workers' help".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Radically different option:

> Her co-workers viewed newcomers as alien and she was no exception. To offer
>   help was beyond them, as they avoided her instinctively.